# XCode allow permission to open a file

Tags: c++, xcode

This is a very simple problem that I can't find the solution to. I have a C++ application running on XCode that uses csvstream to read in files. Whenever the application ran, it would always ask me to allow XCode to access directories on my mac. I would always click allow. Now, I accidentally clicked don't allow and don't know how to get back to the settings of allow. The csvstream keeps throwing the error of "Error opening file" because I accidentally took away permission from XCode to access files on my computer. How do I undo this?

Answer (score 5):

You could try in `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Privacy`

Scroll down the left side, there should be one says `Full Disk Access`. In there, you could add `Xcode`, or check it if it was unchecked. This should let you read all files if you run the program inside Xcode.

Similarly, in the same page, you can add Xcode to `Files and Folders` instead if you only want to give access to certain folders in your computer.

---

If this doesn't work, in Xcode, open `Project Navigator`, which should be in the left sidebar, or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Under `Product`, right click on the output program(not the product folder), and click `Show in Finder`, then drag the program into `Full Disc Access` or `Files and Folders` from earlier.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much. This was so frustrating and I couldn't find anything online about it.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I have access to some files and folders (as before), such as `Downloads`, but not others such as `Documents` despite granting both Xcode and the app itself full disc access. Any ideas?
I'm running the app on `My Mac (Designed for iPad)` with Xcode 14.3.1.